# Is there an inject equivalent for Haskell in the context of free monads

Tags: scala, haskell, free-monad

I'm trying to translate [this Scala's `cats` example](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/freemonad.html) about composing free monads.

The gist of the example seems to be the decomposition of separate concerns into separate data types:

```hs
data Interact a = Ask (String -> a) | Tell String a deriving (Functor)

data DataOp = AddCat String | GetAllCats [String] deriving (Functor)

type CatsApp = Sum Interact DataOp
```

Without having these two separate concerns, I would build the "language" for `Interact` operations as follows:

```hs
ask :: Free Interact String
ask = liftF $ Ask id

tell :: String -> Free Interact ()
tell str = liftF $ Tell str ()
```

However, if I want to use `ask` and `tell` in a program that also uses `DataOp` I cannot define them with the types above, since such a program will have type:

```hs
program :: Free CatsApp a
```

In `cats`, for the definition of the `tell` and `ask` operations they use an `InjectK` class, and an `inject` method from `Free`:

```scala
class Interacts[F[_]](implicit I: InjectK[Interact, F]) {
  def tell(msg: String): Free[F, Unit] = Free.inject[Interact, F](Tell(msg))
  def ask(prompt: String): Free[F, String] = Free.inject[Interact, F](Ask(prompt))
}
```

What puzzles me is that somehow the positional information of the functors (`DataOp` is on the left, `Interact` is on the right) seems to be irrelevant (which is quite nice).

Are there similar type-classes and functions that could be used to solve this problem in an elegant manner using Haskell?

Comment: I suspect the positional information is encoded in the `implicit I: InjectK[Interact, F]`, which tells you how to inject `Interact`s into `F`s.  Wherever `Interacts` is instantiated will have to give that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in [*Data Types à la Carte*](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~W.Swierstra/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf). The Scala library you demonstrated looks like a fairly faithful translation of the original Haskell. The gist of it is, you write a class representing a relationship between a functor `sup` which "contains" a functor `sub`:

```
class (Functor sub, Functor sup) => sub :-<: sup where
    inj :: sub a -> sup a
```

(These days you might use a [`Prism`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html#t:Prism), because they can both inject and project.) Then you can use the usual technique of composing the base functors of your free monads using the functor coproduct, implement `:-<:` for the two cases of `Sum`,

```
instance Functor f => f :-<: f where
    inj = id
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => f :-<: (Sum f g) where
    inj = InL
instance (Functor f, Functor g, Functor h, f :-<: g) => f :-<: (Sum h g) where
    inj = InR . inj
```

and make instruction sets composable by abstracting over the base functor.

```
ask :: Interact :-<: f => Free f String
ask = liftF $ inj $ Ask id

tell :: Interact :-<: f => String -> Free f ()
tell str = liftF $ inj $ Tell str ()

addCat :: DataOp :-<: f => String -> Free f ()
addCat cat = liftF $ inj $ AddCat cat ()

getCats :: DataOp :-<: f => Free f [String]
getCats = liftF $ inj $ GetCats id
```

Now you can write a program which uses both `Interact` and `DataOp` without making reference to a particular sum type.

```
myProgram :: (Interact :-< f, DataOp :-< f) => Free f ()
myProgram = ask >>= addCat
```

None of this is particularly better than the standard MTL approach, though.

Comment: As I climb up the FP ladder all the roads lead to lenses :) Now I have to figure out how to solve the overlapping instances problem that I get if I try to interpret this using IO. But that's topic for another question. I'll also give it a try at the MTL approach.

Comment: And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47431466/how-are-these-two-instances-overlapping-involving-out-of-scope-types) is the error I was referring to. I'm really puzzled about that second instance, which shouldn't be :(

Comment: Actually the paper you referred to mentions the fact that overlapping instances are needed. So another argument in favor of MTL.

Comment: I've tried stacking monads (although I do not use transformers), but I cannot imagine how cross cutting concerns could be nicely separated with the MTL approach. [Here is my new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579216/doing-dependency-injection-using-monad-stacks)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson How does one interpret `myProgram`?